# convert .htaccess to web.config on iis

Tags: php, iis, .htaccess

please could anyone help me. I have a.htaccess file that worked locally on php application uisng zend frame work. Now my application is hosted on windows with iis6.0. My application doest not load when open it on the browser. i quess there is a way one can convert .htaccess file to web.config file. 
this is the re-write case-http://localhost/app 
( will be re-written as:  http://localhost/app/auth/login). it is a zend frame work application.All i want to do is to convert this .htaccess to web.config 
Can anyone help me? here is my code:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/ first link when you google ".htaccess to web.config". did it help ?

Comment: Thank you remi. I do not understand this line in the web.config example that i saw on the url...<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It looks like your rule just wants to make sure that if the file or directory exists do nothing, otherwise rewrite to index.php.

Comment: When i uploaded my files, i got this page error: Page not found;HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Technical Information (for support personnel)

•Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search for the words HTTP and 404.
•Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Web Site Setup, Common Administrative Tasks, and About Custom Error Messages.

Comment: Apologies, I just noticed the comment about your application running in IIS 6.0. The config above require IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 with URL Rewrite enabled. Unfortunately in IIS 6 there is no automatic way to enable that with just IIS, you will need something like Helicon's Rewriter or some other product.

Comment: Thank you carlos. i will try Helicon's Rewriter and any other available one and get back to you. im really greatful for your support